# Zend $db->quote not encoding special characters

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm trying to use Zend's **insert** with the following string:

```
Almoço
```

Whether or not I use zend's **quoteInto** function, the string is inserted into the database as:

```
AlmoÃ§o
```

How do I fix it so that the string I write/read to/from the database is the same as the original string?

Comment: What's special in `ç`? Why do you think it should be quoted?

Comment: i don't know. if it wasn't special wouldn't it work?

Comment: i don't think it needs to be quoted. I just tried quoting because it didn't work without quoting. (although I think that *update* quotes the string anyway)

Comment: It would work if you used proper charset connection setting and proper encoding in DB

Comment: I'm using **latin1_swedish_ci** which is the proper one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a proper encoding (for db columns and connection) that has `ç` character in its character set.

In this case it's presumably `UTF-8`